# Question mark before dot in Dart

Tags: syntax, dart, bloc

What's the meaning of the question mark in this piece of code? And when am I supposed to use it? My code functions the same way with or without the question mark.

```
void dispose(){
  bloc?.dispose();
  super.dispose();
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The question mark is one of the null-aware operators in Dart. In this example it says: call the `dispose()` method ***only*** if `bloc` is not null. Without the question mark, if `bloc` was null when it tried to call `dispose()` a `NoSuchMethodError` would be thrown.

There is a useful section on the Dart site about null-aware operators:

https://dart.dev/codelabs/dart-cheatsheet